# How to mock the class method using NUnit test

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mocking, nunit

Please let me know How do I Mock my "GetStatus" method which is available inside my controller.

**This is my Test Method**

```
     public async Task ShouldReturnOKStatus()
        {
            var EodCheckManager = new Mock<IEodCheckManager>();
            EodCheckManager.Setup(x => x.GetEodStatus(executionDate)).Returns(Task<int>); // Task<int> It failed with error here - Error message -Task<int> is a Type which is not valid in given context  
EodCheckManager.Setup(x => x.GetEodStatus(criteria)).ReturnsAsync(()=>1);
            // Act
            var response = await command.GetCheckAsync(executionDate);
            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetCheckAsync([Fromuri] DateTime executionDate)
{
try
{
  int Status = await this.eodManager.GetStatus(executionDate);
  // some other code
}
}
```

Basically below is the code for GetStatus method which I need to mock

```
public async Task<int> GetStatus(string executionDate)
        {
            int jobCompleted = await this.eodManager.GetStatus(executionDate);
            return jobCompleted;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the line

```
EodCheckManager.Setup(x => x.GetEodStatus(executionDate)).Returns(Task<int>);
```

to read something more like

```
EodCheckManager.Setup(x => x.GetEodStatus(It.IsAny<string>)).ReturnsAsync(200);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, un fortunately this code did not work , I am still seeing value whatever I have set in mock is not being passed in controller class while debugging

Comment: Basically I need to return as 1 - I tried instead of 200 changed to1 - I still don't see that value is being passed in my controller class

Comment: The code you show isn’t complete enough to see for sure… you have injected EodCheckManager.Object in eodManager in the controller constructor, haven’t you?

Comment: yes that's correct , I just some how i need to set 1 as return value from my method